# Mobile web should have different design for iOS and Android?

Tags: website-design, mobile, web-app, android, ios

I've been developing a new hybrid app and as a web-app it is supported in both android and iPhone phones which can be seen here: http://www.fitnessmealplanner.com

The question is: due to people being used to a certain mobile app behaviour in their platform(iOs/Android) should I still consider customising the UX for each, and if so how?

Comment: It depends. there are arguments for both. Many of the arguments aren't even UX focused (such as time to market, maintenance costs, etc.). It all depends on the needs of your particular project.

Answer (score 1):

Forget the "platform wars" and make the application user friendly from a touch perspective. The most important aspect you must try to achieve is to deliver a seamless experience across multiple platforms (make your app look and feel the same as much as you can on all platforms).

As I see your application is not a very complicated so that shouldn't be so hard to achieve, think about screen sizes, where your app is used, finger reach and easy navigation etc.

Answer (score 0):

My rule of thumb (which pretty much merges with @DA01's comment), is **"Do as much as you can, but don't do more than needed"**.

Maybe, if you wanted to give each platform its different design guidelines to appeal everybody, you could simply make a native app *(do as much as you can)*. They tend to be a better choice for users, rather than accessing a website, and if you wanted to put your web app into an app using phonegap, cordova or whatever technology, they tend to be much much less touch responsive than a native. Terrible drawbacks, is that you'd need to design and develop both apps *(don't do more than needed)*. The codebase could be the same, into different languages, but anyway you'd still need to make a looooot more work.

On the other side, I think we all get used to platform-agnostic web designs on mobile devices. What I'd never recommend is to stick to a platform when thinking on designing a mobile website. Haven't you felt cold sweat when navigating though a mobile site with the *top back* pattern from iOS, using a design style from iOS 3 or 4? **If you use a simple, responsive design, you're good to go.**